# uiimageview addSubView not working as intended?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

I have an uiImageview which is intended to use in multiple viewControllers.

What I am thinking is an independant UiImageview that can bind and

unbind from viewController to viewController if needed.

Here is my bind/ unbind part of code.

```
@synthesize uiImgView1;

-(void) sendUIObjToViewController : (UIImageView*)imgView : (UIViewController*)vController{
    [vController.view addSubview:imgView];
}

-(UIImageView*)constructUiImgView : (NSString*) imgAddress{
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)];
    [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgAddress]];
    return imgView;
}

-(void) construct : (UIViewController*) vController{
   uiImgView1 = [self constructImgView : @"abc.png"];
   [self sendUIObjToViewController : uiImgView1 : vController];
}
```

If I call addSubView method from scope of constructUiImgView,

addSubView works.

```
-(UIImageView*)constructUiImgView : (NSString*) imgAddress : (viewController*)vController{
   UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)];
   [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgAddress]];
   [vController.view addSubView imgView];
   return imgView;
}
```

However, that means constructed uiImageView is depandant to one

specific viewController and I don't want to do that.

and If I call sendUiObjToViewController method, uiImageView

should bind to view of viewController but not works.

Am I doing some mistake of referencing variable or something??

My knowledge of Object-c is very limited so I really

need you guys help. Could you tell me what is wrong with my code?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to use the same instance of UIImageView in different UIViewControllers? What advantages are gained from doing that?

Comment: well... lets suppose this code will be packaged and can be used application to application. I am looking for the way to implement this UIImageView without bothering viewController.m part as minimum as possible. Like... [menuClass setMenuToThisViewController : self];